# Visual Studio Code, Python Run/Debug

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-16.04

Whenever I try to run/debug any python script in Visual Studio Code (Ubuntu 16.04), it only executes once and then stops reacting to any debugging command (F5/Ctrl+F5/Shift+F5, etc.).

I feel like I am missing something simple, but I haven't found anything related to that issue.

The MWE:

```
import sys

def main(args):
    print('123')
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

'123' is only printed once and there is no indication of running debug afterwards.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue, and the only ways I have been able to work around this are to either restart Visual Studio Code or to run the script from the terminal.

For example, a script named **myCounter.py** would be run with

> .\myCounter.py

Comment: I should add, I am running on windows, but linux uses ./ to execute, so might have to change to forward slash maybe?

Comment: As far as I found out, it was a bug, it was fixed for the Windows version, but not for Ubuntu